# Как правильно составить синтаксис?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно составить синтаксис?

```
var Array = {
'cfg' : '<div class="asd" onclick="function('asd')"></div>';
};
```

Ругается на апостроф

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но тем не менее: имейте в виду, называть переменные именами встроенных типов — это не очень здоровая практика. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно было экранировать одинарные ковычки и убрать точку с запятой в массиве, вот рабочий вариант:

```
var Array = {
'cfg' : '<div class="asd" onclick="function(\'asd\')"></div>'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте присмотримся к строке

```
'<div class="asd" onclick="function('asd')"></div>'
```

Представим, что мы интерпретатор JS и читаем эту строку:

```
' // открылась кавычка
  // дальше строка внутри кавычек:
    <div class="asd" onclick="function(
' // закрылась кавычка!
asd // какая-то ерунда, что это вообще?
' // снова открылась кавычка и началась строка.
    )"></div>
'
```

Чтобы не делать таких ошибок, тренируйтесь выполнять JS в уме. Просто представьте, что вы — браузер, например. :)

Comment: надеюсь браузер не IE6? ))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский притворяться IE6 опасно для психики — можно не вернуться обратно.